# PPTP VPN connection with dd-wrt terminates

Tags: 10.10, vpn, pptp, dd-wrt

I have problems with connection to DD-WRT router with PPTP server installed. Win7 has no problems with connection to it. But in Ubuntu I'm getting all the time:

```
Dec 28 21:52:14 IT-nb pppd[4209]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Dec 28 21:52:14 IT-nb pppd[4209]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Dec 28 21:52:14 IT-nb pppd[4209]: Using interface ppp0
Dec 28 21:52:14 IT-nb pppd[4209]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Dec 28 21:52:18 IT-nb pppd[4209]: Connection terminated.
Dec 28 21:52:18 IT-nb pppd[4209]: Exit.
```

Answer (score 3):

Whereas Windows appears to try different options automatically, you must configure Network Manager more manually.

[image: Advanced Options screenshot]

In Advanced Options there are a number of options; you need to find a combination that works.

Comment: It's good idea but I'm looking for a screenshot with working profile to connect to dd-wrt. It's possible that smth wrong I've set on server or another version of client required.

Comment: If it works in Windows then the server is working; it's just one of the above settings. If you don't want to try a little trial-and-error I'd suggest you head over to the DD-WRT forums. They should be able to give you the exact settings.

Comment: @StalkerNOVA, for PPTP VPN in general, I found that ticking the first two checkboxes under **Security and Compression** is decisive factor of the VPN connecting or not. Note that these finding is from free PPTP services.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also Kvpnc, I used it to connect via PPTP and it worked. You can install Kvpnc directly from the Ubuntu Software Center:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/maverick/kvpnc/

You can use the guide here, there are some screenshot on how to configure your PPTP connection:

http://vimalkumar.in/2008/09/19/howto-connect-to-a-pptp-vpn-server-using-kvpnc/